# get selected item from combobox created inside a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, combobox, actionlistener

I have this code that reads data from my database and displays it in a combobox:

```
                //this is inside a thread
                @Override
                public void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {

                    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(input);
                    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                    Hashtable response = parser.parse(reader);

                    java.util.List allResult = (java.util.List) response.get("AllResult");
                    System.out.println(allResult);
                    try {
                        String[] data = new String[allResult.size()];
                        for (int i = 0; i < allResult.size(); i++) {

                            Object obj = allResult.get(i);
                            String result = (String) ((Hashtable) obj).get("Status");
                            String brokerName = (String) ((Hashtable) obj).get("brokerName");
                            if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                                    data[i] = brokerName;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                       ComboBox brokerNames = new ComboBox(data);
                       assignCon.addComponent(brokerNames);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } //all these work well
```

I need to get the selected item from that combobox when I click on a submit button like this:

```
            Button ass = new Button("ASSIGN");
    ass.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                         String names = brokerNames.getSelectedItem.toString();
           }
            });
```

Right now, it is giving me errors due to the fact that I cannot access brokerNames from outside the thread. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or a much better way to go about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are off as this has absolutely **nothing** to do with Threads and all to do with variable scope and nothing more as you've declared brokerNames within a local block, making the variable invisible to any code outside of the block. Fix that -- make it a field within the class.

On a side note, if you are adding brokerName to the GUI within a background thread, then you've got dangerous code for other reasons as you'r changing the state of visible Swing components (the container which holds brokerName) off of the Swing event thread. This won't cause the compiler issue that you're experiencing but could cause intermittent hard to debug exceptions to be thrown. I would add the JComboBox to the GUI on GUI creation, not within a background thread.

Comment: okay thank you @Hovercraft, I have done that - added the combobox on gui creation and made it a field within the class. I then used this line of code within my thread: brokerNames.addItem(data)
But it gives me the names in this format: ljava.lang.string;@22e86b30
please what am I doing wrong?